# Access CasperJS variable from evaluate method

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a website. I have a website where it has a `select` element,  so after selecting the element, another select box appears dynamically and so on.

Either I can use `waitForSelector` method, but I don't know the `id` of the dynamic element before hand, or I can use `wait` to wait for a few seconds.

But, for dynamically loaded content, the page will send an ajax request. I use the functions `onResourceRequest` and `onResourceReceived` to keep a count, such that whenever a resource is requested I increment the count and after the event `reource.received` or `onResourceError` I could decrement the count and check iff the count is `0`, I will move forward or else wait for requests to be completed.

But I scrape the page using `evaluate` method and the variable on which I increment and decrement count is in CasperJS context. How should I access the variable declared in CasperJS from `evaluate` function, so that I could check whether all the requests hava been finished or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `evaluate()` is sandboxed, you can't directly access variables defined outside. There are multiple ways to pass data out of the page context (console message, alert, `page.onCallback`, `evaluate()` result), but there is only one way to pass data in and that is by directly passing it to `evaluate()` as an argument.

The question is how you can pass it in so that your script makes sense.

#### Pass it every time

Whenever you do something in the page context that requires that variable, you can pass it in. This might not work as expected when you do a lot of asynchronous work before using that information as it can be stale at that time.

#### Proactively put it into the page context

Whenever that count changes, you can put that information into the page context onto the global scope:

```js
// do this inside of the `reource.received` and `onResourceError` events
casper.evaluate(function(count){
    window._myCount = count;
}, count);
```

Then whenever you need to use that information inside of the page context you just need to access it as it already there in `window._myCount`.

---

You can more or less freely nest steps such as `waitForSelector()`:

```js
casper.waitForSelector(selector1, function(){
    var dynamicId = this.evaluate(function(){
        ...
        return dynId;
    });
    this.waitForSelector("#" + dynamicId);
});

casper.then(function(){
    // this is only executed when the previous `"#" + dynamicId` was found
});
```